# Does the oleDB API allow for pooling and multi user use?

Tags: c#, oledb

I work with an application that kicks every user out whenever multiple people try to work on the same file.

I have looked and [this](http://immitev.blogspot.ca/2005/01/where-is-ole-db-connection-pooling_28.html) helped me better understand the problem that I am facing. Would switching and using c#'s [sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) class serve solve my problem?

Comment: That completely depends on what your problem is.  Do you get an error?

Comment: Files can be inserted, deleted, edited, etc, but whenever, more than one person tries to do so at the same time, they are all kicked out. I.e. the application crashes.

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out why it's crashing.